# Unable to remove extension from exclusion (Windows Defender 10)

Tags: windows, powershell

I have a problem deleting the following extension from the exclusions ( I accidentally added it).  I have tried to boot to safe mode and delete by using Powershell, and clicked "remove" manually:

> powershell -Command Remove-MpPreference -ExclusionExtension ".exe"

However, it didn't work out (not the same with others as I can add/remove normal), you can see "remove" button is still available. I checked the registry path as well, it doesn't have the path "Exclusions"

[Exclusion-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xokOe.png)

Please help!

Comment: What if you try `-ExclusionExtension 'exe'` (extension without the dot) ?

Comment: I did, but same outcome. I'm not sure why it didn't disappear... I tried to add this extension on another machine and was able to remove it normally. :(